# Changing 'children' node in json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am attempting to use d3s Collapsible tree. I am using a node hierarchy as seen in many of the examples. However, I am attempting to put my own node hierarchy data set e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nszmg/2/

```
 var flare = {

"Name": "Example",
"children": [


    {
     "BName":"Ja",   
     "Email":"",
     "children":[
     {

        "NickName":"NC",
        "id":2

     },
     {

        "NickName":"Fi",
        "id":68

     }
  ],

 }
     ]};
```

Instead of having 'children' am I able to change it to another name? I have tried to find similar requests but havent found any to match.

I would appreicate if anyone had any advice of examples.

Comment: do you want to change the property name `children` to something else

Comment: yes i would like to change to to something else e.g. inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [*children* function of the tree layout.](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout#wiki-children)

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width])
    .children(function(d) { return d.children1; });
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mEyQW/) is a forked fiddle with "children1" as property.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! However, when a link is revealed I cannot make it toggle back into it's previous form. Any idea why?

Comment: I guess there are some `d.children` snippets that I forgot to change to d.children1. Search for children, children1, _children, and _children1.

Answer (score 0):

`children` is the key used in the core js to parse your parameter, so in case you want to change to another, I am afraid of you have to change the core but I don't encourage you do so.

Comment: and that's the only option?

Comment: another way is that you have to build a parse for your dataset to transform it to d3.js structure